# C# How to add method-call to a callback-chain (where Action is in a class that is passed on)

Tags: c#, callback, action, chain

I am making a Command-handling system for a game I'm working on.

The idea is, that when a command is detected a Command-object is created like this:

```
{
    string commandID;
    string[] parameters;

    public Action onCommandComplete;

    public Command( string input, Action callback )
    {
        //parse input string

        onCommandComplete = callback;
    }

    //...
}
```

And this command is passed through a hierarchy of CommandHandlers, depending on game state and command type:

```
public class Game
{
    CommandHandler commandHandlerA;
    CommandHandler commandHandlerB;
    //and so on...

    public void HandleCommand (string input)
    {
        var command = new Command (input, ContinueGame)

        if (someConidition)
        {
            commandHandlerA.Handle (command);
        }
        else
        {
            commandHandlerA.Handle (command);
        }
    }

    void ContinueGame()
    {
        //Game goes on...
    }
}



public class CommandHandlerA
{
    CommandHandler commandHandlerC;

    public void Handle (Command command)
    {
        //do stuff
        commandHandlerC.Handle (command); //pass on command
    }
}



public class CommandHandlerC
{
    public void Handle (Command command)
    {
        //do stuff
        command.onCommandComplete(); //return the control
    }
}
```

The reason I use actions is, that some commands are handled async.

This works very well! But I found a case, where I need to do something in a CommandHandler (in the middle of the chain), but after the command at the end of the chain has been handled. If I was only passing on pure Actions I would do like this:

```
public class CommandHandlerA
{
    CommandHandler commandHandlerC;

    public void Handle (Action onCommandComplete)
    {
        //do stuff
        commandHandlerC.Handle (() => DoThisStuffUponReturningControl(command)); //pass on command and "on the way back" do DoThisStuffUponReturningControl
    }
    void DoThisStuffUponReturningControl (Action onCommandComplete)
    {
        //do stuff
        onCommandComplete(); //continue callback
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do this, when I pass on the Command-object with the Action inside. Must be something I'm missing here, right?

I feel it should be very easy and that it's something that I just didn't think of. Any help and ideas will be very valued!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to add method call to any delegate including `Action`, you can use `+=` operator for this.

Here is simple example:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action firstAction = () => Console.WriteLine("First action");
            Command command = new Command("input1", firstAction);
            Action secondAction = () => Console.WriteLine("Second action");
            command.AddAction(secondAction);
            command.Invoke();
            Console.ReadLine();

            Action thirdAction = () => Console.WriteLine("Third action");
            command.AddAction(thirdAction);
            command.RemoveAction(secondAction);
            command.Invoke();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }

    public class Command
    {

        Action onCommandComplete;

        public Command(string input, Action callback)
        {
            //parse input string
            if (callback is not null)
                onCommandComplete = callback;
        }

        public void AddAction(Action action)
        {
            if (action is not null && onCommandComplete is not null)
                onCommandComplete += action;
        }

        public void RemoveAction(Action action)
        {
            if (action is not null && onCommandComplete is not null)
                onCommandComplete -= action;
        }

        public void Invoke()
        {
            onCommandComplete?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.